# What is the default structure packing using cl/gcc/clang?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, cl, struct-member-alignment

On msdn for cl compiler option /Zp, it is mentioned that "Packs structures on 8-byte boundaries (default)." Does that mean that if there a data type of size > 8 bytes, by default (no compiler option or pragma pack) it would not be naturally aligned and rather will have 8 byte alignment. If yes, is that case with GCC/clang?

I checked on GCC, using `-fpack-struct`and `__uint128_t`, that it does not have any such default. For example `sizeof(tStruct)` is 32 and 24:

```
struct tStruct {
uint64_t    a;
__uint128_t b;
};
```

I am not able to check the same on windows as it does not provide any data type > 8  bytes.

Comment: "Naturally aligned" means "aligned per the CPU recommendations", which means that it primarily makes sense for types that map 1-to-1 to CPU types. `__uint128_t` does not. It's probably synthesized from two 64 bit types. Thus, its natural alignment is that of a 64 bit type.

Comment: Natural aligned means size of the data type and in case of __uint128_t it is 16 and hence the sizeof(tStruct) comes out to be 32.

Comment: Well, `int[4]` is a 128 bits type in MSVC++ but I think everyone agrees that its natural alignment is 4 bytes. That said, MSVC++ in fact does have _scalar_ data types which are 128 bits, e.g. `__m128i`.

Comment: MSalters is right that it is aligned per the CPU recommendations but GCC implements `__uint128_t` on x86 with SSE2 which requires 16-byte alignment. It may be different on different architectures.